# Is there an existing buff I can give to my PCs for using a general map of locations item?

Tags: dnd-5e, maps, exploration

I am currently running the Lost Mine of Phandelver campaign and I am considering the idea of retrieving a general map of locations as a hook to get my players to visit Daran Edermath in Phandalin (he's a retired adventurer).

My question is: Is there an existing buff I can give to my PCs for using a general map of locations item? (apart from just knowing the surrounding locations)

Thanks!

Comment: How detailed is this map? Is it just a general map of locations or is it really detailed and specific?

Comment: That would be a general map of locations. (The Sword Coast region map)

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here? Why do you feel they *need* some sort of buff for using a map? Is there any reason why *just* knowing the surrounding locations seems insufficient to you? A little more information about what you're looking for and what brought you to ask this question might help the community better tailor their answers to your specific needs.

Comment: Do you mean buffs similar to spell effects and blessings or do you mean something along the lines of "advantage on survival checks"? If you come from an MMO background, buffs could have broad meanings.

Comment: You've already ran into one of the most common problems DM'ing: fear (often justified) that the players will miss something that you thought was very clever or supposed to be important. You may want to ask a separate question about how to handle the situation from that perspective, I think you'll get better results.

Comment: The other comments got it pretty good, but I'll just add this: Yes, there is a buff. It's called the "I'm the DM and you get a buff" buff. Not quite what you are looking for, but its the only thing I can think of. You could have them meet a map maker on the road? I think a better question would be "How do I get my players to use a map?" or even "How do I get my players to get to more of the content I've prepared without railroading them?"